# Convert JavaScript file to JSON

Tags: javascript, android, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

I am writing an Android app where I'm getting a .js (JavaScript) file from a url and I want to read its contents. Is there any way to convert this file to a JSONArray or JSONObject? Or a direct way to parse the .js file itself?

Comment: If he's asking what it sounds like he's asking, this isn't a dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean can you create a data structure out of raw JavaScript, then no.

You can't convert a string of arbitrary JavaScript to JSON except in the degenerate sense that the entire string is a valid JSON item of type 'string'.  This is because the syntax of JS covers a much larger domain than JSON.  For example, what kind of JSON structure would you expect to represent the following JS?

```
while (true) { }
```

If your intent is to traverse the JS and pull data structures out of it, you're probably going to need something like a full JavaScript parsing engine.

If on the other hand you've phrased the question badly and the '.js' file you're fetching is really a JSON file, then the question is answered in the marked duplicate.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. You have understood correctly. Is there such a JavaScript parsing engine available for java?

Comment: Nope. It's not. I already know how to parse a JSON file. I know there is a difference. Despite the bad phrasing, and what it may imply. ;) Thanks to your short explanation I know what to look for.